# Laravel. Testing cron jobs

Tags: laravel-5, cron, integration-testing

I have some scheduled tasks (sending emails, changing data in database) that runs daily, monthly or every first Monday in a month. Here is an example from `App\Console\Kernel.php`:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->call(function(){
         Message::deleteOld();
     })->monthly();
}
```

Is there a way to test this functionality? I mean some integration test that would check if the task runs at the right time and does the right job.

Comment: Haven't fully tested but you can simulate the carbon time, don't know if kernel cronjobs of laravel use Carbon as a core with his time         
`$first_day_next_month = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonth()->startOfMonth();
          \Carbon\Carbon::setTestNow($first_day_next_month);
          dd(\Carbon\Carbon::now()); //New time
`